# Using a List with icons on an Android

Tags: android, list, android-listview, icons, xamarin

I am coding an Android application in Xamarin and have a question about a List.
I am currently coding many TextView objects on screen with contact details.

This is not displaying how I wish it to and I am wanting to know the correct programming object to use that is the same as the Settings list on many Android devices.

This list is the list that has:

- Wi-Fi
- BlueTooth
- Data Usage
- etc

Each of these items has an icon and the items can be clicked on.

Is this called a List, a ListView or something else? Also, if possible, may I have a link to some example code on how to use this object?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called custom listview, you get a lot of tutorials if you search that:
For an example code, check this out.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html